# opencv optical flow algorithm multi-threaded implementation didn't speedup

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, opticalflow

I'm setting up a real-time video stitching project,with opencv optical flow algorithms.The problem I'm facing is that the optical flow calculation takes a lot of time,I'm trying to use it in several threads but it doestn't speed up at all.Is there any wrong with my code,or is there any optical flow algorithms that can replace the one opencv provides?Thanks in advance.
Here is my test code:

```cpp
Ptr<cuda::DensePyrLKOpticalFlow> brox[6];


void callOptical(GpuMat d_frame0f, GpuMat d_frame1f, GpuMat d_flow, Stream stream,int i)
{
    brox[i]->calc(d_frame0f, d_frame1f, d_flow, stream);
    brox[i]->calc(d_frame1f, d_frame0f, d_flow, stream);
}


int main()
{
    String filename[12] = { "l0.png", "r0.png", "l1.png", "r1.png", "l2.png", "r2.png", "l3.png", "r3.png", "l4.png", "r4.png", "l5.png", "r5.png" };
    Mat frame[12];
    GpuMat d_frame[12];
    GpuMat d_framef[12];
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        frame[2 * i] = imread(filename[2 * i], IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        frame[2 * i + 1] = imread(filename[2 * i + 1], IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        d_frame[2 * i].upload(frame[2 * i]);
        d_frame[2 * i + 1].upload(frame[2 * i + 1]);
        brox[i] = cuda::DensePyrLKOpticalFlow::create(Size(7, 7));
    }
    GpuMat d_flow[6];
    GpuMat pre_flow[6];
    Stream stream[6];


    vector<std::thread> threads;

    const int64 start = getTickCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        threads.emplace_back(
            callOptical,
            d_frame[2 * i],
            d_frame[2 * i + 1],
            d_flow[i],
            stream[i],
            i
            );
    }

    for (std::thread& t : threads)
        t.join();

    const double timeSec = (getTickCount() - start) / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Brox : " << timeSec << " sec" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not parallel - t.join()!!! You need call t.detach() and waiting  while all threads is not stopped.

**Edit**: test for sequence:

```
void callOptical(GpuMat d_frame0f, GpuMat d_frame1f, GpuMat d_flow, Stream stream,int i)
{
    std::cout << i << " begin..." <<  std::endl;
    brox[i]->calc(d_frame0f, d_frame1f, d_flow, stream);
    brox[i]->calc(d_frame1f, d_frame0f, d_flow, stream);
    std::cout << i << " end!" <<  std::endl;
}
```

**Edit**: use openmp!

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    callOptical(d_frame[2 * i], d_frame[2 * i + 1], d_flow[i], stream[i], i);
}
```

Comment: As I know, the child threads will be parallel,t.join() just means that the main thread will wait until the sub threads complete, and the calculation is all in the child threads.Is anything wrong with my understanding?

Comment: Thank you, but the t.join() works even better than pragma.

Comment: With join your code is not parallel - use detach with waiting result or openmp.

Comment: Using of join is tested to be parallel,maybe multi-threads is not safe in opencv that cause other threads wait until the running thread finishes.